# while I'm getting infinite while loop in java

Tags: java, while-loop

I want to write a code which loops in a 2d array, the main method is findVal which gets a 2d array and a value and return true if the value is in the array,  I used a binary search code to loop through a single  row of the array and another method which goes down in rows in the 2d array, the problem is when I run a tester it doen't open the terminal window and it looks like my loop is infinite, my code is the following

```
public static int linearSearch(int [] arr, int num)
    {
        int pos=0;
        while ((arr[pos]<num)&&(pos<arr.length-1))
            pos++;
        if(arr[pos]==num){return pos;}
        else {return -1;}
    }
public static boolean findVal(int [][] m, int val)
    {
        int n=m.length;
        int j=m.length-1, i=0;
        while (i<=j)
        {
            if(val == m[i][j]){return true;}
            
            else if(val > m[i][j] ){

                if(linearSearch(m[i],val) !=-1){return true;}

            }
            else{
                i++;
            }

        }

        return false;
    }
```

can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
**Note: I can't use nested loops neither run through n*n in a for loop.**

Comment: In `findVal`, if `val > m[i][j]` and `linearSearch(m[i],val)` returns `-1`, then your loop will repeat without updating any variables.

Comment: I recommend using your debugger to step through the code one statement at a time and see what happens. You'd then discover that you are entering the second branch (the `else if`) but then the next `if` inside of it is not fulfilled and execution continues forever this way because nothing is changing that would make a difference in what code path is taken next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your else if condition is causing the loop to go infinite.

```
 else if(val > m[i][j] ){

                if(linearSearch(m[i],val) !=-1){return true;}

            }
```

In case -1 is returned from the `linearSearch(m[i],val)` . You are not increasing i or j which in turn is causing the same values of i and j to be evaluated again and again in the while loop.

Try to do a i++ in case the value from `linearSearch(m[i],val) == -1` that will fix the issue of infinite loop

Answer (score 2):

Your `while` body has an `if`-`else if`-`else` structure with three branches. The first uses a `return` statement to exit the method, so that won't cause an infinite loop. The third increments `i` so that should eventually cause the loop to end. It's the second one that's the issue. It contains a conditional `return` statement. However, if that condition is not met, the loop body does *nothing*. That means that the loop condition won't change, and the same branch is chosen every time.